# PHP Simple HTML DOM Won't Work on external host

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have developed a code which works perfectly fine on my own local Apache, but as soon as i transferred the file it stopped working. NO error messages, the page is blank!

I am using HostGator, I contacted their support they were very USELESS! and pretty much told me i am on my own. 
I am pretty sure the code is OK, also all the links, and configs inside my code are verified too, so I am pretty sure there is something with hostgator.

I checked "allow_url_fopen" in ezConfig, it's ON.. is there anything you guys can help me with?!
Anyone had the same issue?!

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check phpinfo() and compare from your server to hostgator.

Comment: you are checking that all functions available are the same. Differences between php versions and installed and allowed functions. Testing on your home apache server usually means a dev environment which = 0 security features. Settings are usually different for an apache server that is open to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the php version on your host is the same as local?

Comment: Maybe not Exactly, but i am pretty sure they both are 5! I don't see how that makes any difference